# Python & Stats: Fit Weibull Distribution using Least Square Method

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I know I can fit Weibull Distribution like this:

```
weibull_params = sp.stats.exponweib.fit(data, floc=0, f0=1)
```

But what method does it use? From [Fitting a Weibull distribution using Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481672/fitting-a-weibull-distribution-using-scipy), it seems like using `Max Likelyhood Method`. Is it possible to switch to `Least Square Method?`

Addtionally, I want to know the quality of each fitting method(the `error`?), but I guess I can google it out and save it for later.

Comment: *"...it seems like using Max Likelyhood Method."*  That is correct, the `fit` method uses maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: Saullo Castro's answer in the link you provided shows a code example on how to switch to LSQ.

Comment: Is it possible, yes of course. But which way do you want to compute mean square distance?  That is, do you want to fit the empirical distribution function of the data to Weibull CDF, or empirical density function to Weibull pdf, or empirical hazard function to Weibull hazard function? Each of those different methods will likely result in different result.   And~, why not using MLE?