# Determine Weibull parameters from data

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy, weibull

I would like to identify the [Weibull parameters](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qfr7xq9aneg7ba/data1.csv?dl=0) (i.e. the shape and scale) of my data.

```
0.022988506
0.114942529
0.218390805
0.114942529
0.149425287
0.114942529
0.068965517
0.068965517
0.034482759
0.022988506
0.022988506
0.022988506
0.022988506
```

I've already tried what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481672/fitting-a-weibull-distribution-using-scipy) proposed, and I'm using Python 3.4.

```
import scipy.stats as s
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats


def weib(x,n,a):
    return (a / n) * (x / n)**(a - 1) * np.exp(-(x / n)**a)


data = np.loadtxt("data1.csv")
print(data)
(loc, scale) = s.exponweib.fit_loc_scale(data, 1, 1)
print('loc is: ',loc, '\n scale is: ', scale)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[0.02298851  0.11494253  0.2183908   0.11494253  0.14942529  0.11494253   0.06896552  0.06896552  0.03448276  0.02298851  0.02298851  0.02298851 0.02298851]
loc is:  0.0574417296258 
scale is:  0.0179259738449
```

I assume that the data in my csv file was read as x-input values, instead of the y-values of the Weibull function.  When I add a second column (or row) with bin, it gives an error that string values can not be converted into floats.

How do I need to modify my csv file in order to use the data within as the y-values of the Weibull function?

I think my problem might be that I don't understand this line:

```py
(loc, scale) = s.exponweib.fit_loc_scale(data, 1, 1)
```

What does `1, 1` represent here?  The parameters should then not be negative.

Comment: When you say you want "the Weibull parameters", do you mean the parameters of the Weibull distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution)?  It has *three* parameters: a shape parameter, plus the location and scale parameters.  `exponweib` is the exponentiated Weibull distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiated_Weibull_distribution), which has *four* parameters (two shape plus location and scale).

Comment: yes, it was meant the 2-parameter-weibull distribution f(x;λ,k), so adapting only shape and scale factors (λ, k). in that case, I shouldnt use exponweib, what to use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `fit` method of `scipy.stats.weibull_min` (which is an alias for `scipy.stats.frechet_r`).  Use the argument `floc=0` to constrain the location to be 0.

```
In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
array([ 0.02298851,  0.11494253,  0.2183908 ,  0.11494253,  0.14942529,
        0.11494253,  0.06896552,  0.06896552,  0.03448276,  0.02298851,
        0.02298851,  0.02298851,  0.02298851])

In [10]: from scipy.stats import weibull_min

In [11]: shape, loc, scale = weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0)

In [12]: shape
Out[12]: 1.3419930069121602

In [13]: scale
Out[13]: 0.084273047253525968
```

Comment: Hi Warren. I used the same function to fit my data. But when I tend to constrain the 'loc' to zero, the returned loc is 0.999999 while my data's min value is 1.  I also tried to constrain the shape parameter to 1 that the distribution will reduce to exponential model, the returned shape parameter is not 1(0.72~). So does it mean that the constrained params for input is not into usage for fit the model ? Can I suppose that all the three parameters are unique for a specified data ? Thanks.

Comment: @yanachen That is too much to discuss in these comments.  You should start a new question.

Comment: Could you please provide an answer for my question. Much thanks to you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991799/are-the-parameters-unique-for-a-given-data