# Fitting Weibull Parameters in C#

Tags: c#, weibull

very similar to the question posted here: [Determine Weibull parameters from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070724/determine-weibull-parameters-from-data)

I have a bunch of data, and I want to extract the Weibull parameters from it using a library in C#. (As opposed to the linked question which uses python)

Comment: It is a math function and you just need to convert to c#.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiated_Weibull_distribution

Comment: Yes, I understand the maths, but I want to know if there is a library where I can give it an array of data, and it calculates the parameters

Comment: Why do you need a library when you can write the code yourself in 10 minutes?

Comment: because one of the parameters is not solved analytically, but numerically, but that's also not that big of a deal, since a library exists in python, I thought that it could have in C# also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MathNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.weibull?view=excel-pia)

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
```