# Weibull fitting of a data histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

Using the following code, I can plot a histogram of my data and the fitting curve to the histogram.

```
mybins = len(data)//20
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5, 3))
(mu,sigma) = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data)
n,bins,patches=ax.hist(data, bins=mybins, density=True, color='green', histtype='stepfilled', linewidth=1) 
ax.axvline(x=data.mean(), color='green', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3)
y = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)
ax.plot(bins,y,'r--',color='green', linewidth=3)
ax.set_xlim(0.5,1.1)
```

This is the output which is correct fot the histogram and its vertical line of mean.
[image]

But, the fitting curve is a normal fitting against the mean.
I need help to implement a **Weibull** fit which should be resulting in a skewed fitting curve according to the data distribution.

Tried using the following from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481672/fitting-a-weibull-distribution-using-scipy):

```
shape, loc, scale = weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0)
plt.plot(data, stats.exponweib.pdf(data, *stats.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=scale, loc=loc)))
plt.hist(data, label='PR', density=True, bins=len(data)//15, color = 'orangered')
plt.axvline(x=data.mean(), color='black', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

And the result is
[image]

**Edit**:
Another try with **sorted** data:

```
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5, 3))
ax.hist(data, bins=len(data)//15, color = 'orangered')
shape, loc, scale = weibull_min.fit(data, floc=0)
plt.plot(data, stats.exponweib.pdf(data, *stats.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=scale, loc=loc)))
plt.show()
```

The result is now much better, but still not yet what it should be, i.e. the fit curve doesn't fit the 'size' of histogram.
[image]

My data can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORHtRTgB5s_0NCQnEa4RKrWg7OT3is7X/view?usp=sharing).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about using [`weibull_min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html) from scipy's stats package

Comment: Still wrong result here

Comment: What you're showing is an effect of plotting unsorted data as a line plot.  Sort the `data` object and everything will be fine.

Comment: @merv suggestion about sorting data gives a much better result, but still not yet as it should be. Please see edit.

Comment: The histogram plot should include the argument `normed=True`.