# Fitting data with a three-parameter Weibull distribution function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

In my data, the first column is the `x` values, and the second column is the `y` values. I want to fit the data with a three-parameter Weibull function to describe the distribution.

I tried to find solutions by many searches, but a [similar post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481672/fitting-a-weibull-distribution-using-scipy) seems to be only for one-column data. I also tried with the libraries `scipy.stats.exponweib` and `scipy.stats.weibull_min`, but failed due to the same problem.

So I tried to define the function and to fit the data with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. The following is the code I used. The `data.txt` file can be downloaded by this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c31SiYtf1s9KG1G7PKkb2Dp995HGlqqH/view?usp=sharing).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Load data
poresize, psd, psd_std = np.loadtxt("data.txt", unpack=True)

# Define the Weibull distribution function with the requested form
def weibull_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * b * (x - c) ** (b - 1) * np.exp(-a * (x - c) ** b)

# Perform curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(weibull_func, poresize, psd, p0=[1, 1, 1])

# Plot the original data and the fitted curve
plt.scatter(poresize, psd, label='Data')
x_range = np.linspace(min(poresize), max(poresize), 100)
plt.plot(x_range, weibull_func(x_range, *popt), 'r-', label='Fitted curve (Weibull)')
plt.xlabel('Particle Size')
plt.ylabel('PSD')
plt.title('Fitting Weibull Distribution')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Display the optimized parameters
a_opt, b_opt, c_opt = popt
print("Optimized Parameters:")
print("a:", a_opt)
print("b:", b_opt)
print("c:", c_opt)
```

The function form is adapted from the [Weibull distribution from Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/weibull.html), but `x` is replaced with `x-c`.
The problem is that I tried many combinations of the initial guess values for `p0`, but none of them could give me a satisfactory result.

Could you please tell me whether there is something fundamentally wrong with the code? Or how can I get the proper initial guess fast?

Comment: What do you mean by one- versus two-column data? Please share a minimal reproducible example as without the data we cannot help you.

Comment: What is PSD? Is it a probability distribution? (i.e. is the integral underneath it equal to 1?) Have you tried fitting with the (more natural) alternative form ```c * a * b * x ** (b - 1) * np.exp(-a * x ** b)``` (which has integral equal to c).

Comment: @jared Hi, thanks for the comment! The data is shared by a link since it has 100 lines. I want to use the first column as x and the second column as y, and fit them with a Weibull function. If anything is unclear, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @FreeAir What's the issue of having x in one column and y in another column? It sounds to me that this is like every other curve fitting problem.

Comment: @lastchance Hi, thanks! Yes, I think the integral area under the line equals 1. Thanks for your advice, I tried your form, and I think it works. Here is the link for the figure https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uREOIRNVYZejjRVq-hvejeIKtRLWCzz7/view?usp=drive_link. Any further suggestions? Could you please tell me the original of the form you proposed?

Comment: @jared There are some existing libraries for the Weibull function fitting, but it seems that they only support one column data, i.e., only input y values. As a result, I cannot use them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two pieces of advice when fitting a function:

1. Understand the function you're trying to fit. In this case, you should realize that it is undefined for `x < c` when `b` is not an integer. (This is because you have `(x-c)^(b-1)`. If `x < c` then `x - c < 0`. If `b` is not an integer then you will be taking a fractional power of a negative number, which produces a complex number.)
2. Plot your data and play around with a model of your function to get a good guess. In this case, I plotted your data and saw that the spike is between `x = 2` and `x = 5` and it spikes up to `y = 1`. Knowing that, I made [this Desmos model](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bgojqlscmk) and played with the variables until I got something decent.

Here is the fixed function that can handle `x < c`:

```py
def weibull_func(x, a, b, c):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    cond = x > c
    xcond = x[cond]
    res[cond] = a*b*(xcond - c)**(b - 1)*np.exp(-a*(xcond - c)**b)
    return res
```

I provided the `curve_fit` call with the guess I got using Desmos:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(weibull_func, poresize, psd, p0=[1.4, 1.93, 2.4])
```

The tuned parameters are:

```py
a = 1.1172264863332277
b = 2.2231297860177226
c = 2.301372954142873
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the solution! That is brilliant. I should be more aware of what the function is, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hello, I found in some cases, the fitting result seems to be not as good as before. Here is the link for the picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uijOiPSB3zuJWyrEKyxjp9ZTfIrtofMy/view?usp=sharing. I found the edge at the left is not very sharp, and the peak of the line is lower than the data. Could you please give me some suggestions on how to improve the result? Or it is what it is situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The general fit looks good (it will never be perfect). It seems like the only issue is that left edge. What is your value for `c` in this case? Note, you might get a better fit of the peak if you trim off some of the initial values and tail values since you know those are 0 and the algorithm doesn't actually need to do any fitting there. In the photo you share it doesn't look to have a ton of extra data, but in the example from your question you do.

Comment: @FreeAir, jared's solution is as good as you are going to get with a (modified) Weibull distribution. But do you need to fit a Weibull distribution? That is usually used for extreme-value statistics, with data over several decadal ranges (and more usually plotted as exceedance rather than a probability distribution). To be honest, a gaussian probably wouldn't be a bad fit to your data. Your "not-so-good" fit actually seems to have remarkable consistency between what are presumably experimental repetitions. The overall data looks like the sum of two distributions.

Comment: Hi @jared, thanks very much! I will try to trim off some initial values and tail values, I think it is straightforward, I just need to modify `cond = x > c`. And maybe it is already very good, I understand that one function may not fit every data set "perfectly".

Comment: Hi @lastchance, thanks very much for the reply! I started with Gaussian distribution, but our previous work used Weibull distribution, so I have to follow. By comparing the results of the two, I think the part around the peak is quite similar, the difference is mainly at the edges. The conclusion I think should be very close.